Is Aycan Sucuk Garlic sausage a pre-cooked deli meat, or a raw meat product requiring cooking?
I've recently been gifted several packs of Sucuk Garlic sausage. specifically this product by a well meaning person.
The purchaser brought this in the EU, and I'm not familiar with the brand, and am uncertain if it is a pre-prepared deli meat product like Salami that can be eaten straight from the packet as it is, or if it is a raw meat product that requires cooking.
Almost all serving suggestions that I've found suggest frying it before consumption, but I don't know if this is simply a cultural preference of the region that it comes from, so am looking for confirmation as to whether it is a raw meat product from a food safety perspective, but also because my culture dictates that we handle and store raw meat in different ways

I don't know aboutthe food safety aspects, but I have eaten sucuk raw and fried, and it is much tastier when fried.

You asked if it can be eaten as-is, or whether it’s an uncooked meat product; but some uncooked meat products can be eaten as-is, and some cooked meat products require further cooking. Please clarify whether you want to know about its rawness or whether you want to know if it can be eaten as-is.

I searched for it and, assuming it's a Turkish sausage with a lot of garlic, I would say it is not cooked. I based this on:

every recipe for using it said to cook it (slice it thin and fry it)
none of the recipes for making it had a cooking step

It is cured and dried, but apparently not cooked.

Aren’t salami and pepperoni cured and dried, but not cooked?

The English wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujuk#Production mentions no cooking step, the German one also describes it as a raw sausage that is cured and generally eaten warm/fried.

Whereever I saw Sucuk sold, it was also stored like a raw meat product, meaning refrigerated. If it where more like salami, then it could be stored unfrigerated but this does not seem to be the case.

@DebbieM. even if salami isn't cooked (I don't know) the question said they have to handle raw and cooked food differently and therefore need to know if it has been cooked.

Given its large Turkish immigrant population this type of sausage is commonly available in Germany. Pregnant women are advised only to eat it cooked due to the (low) risk of toxoplasmosis. Note that this advice applies to all salami type (air dried, uncooked) sausages, at least in Germany and is not specific to sucuk.
Having said this, unlike salami, the taste is geared towards eating it cooked, so your mileage in eating it raw may vary.
The fact that it might be sold refrigerated is neither here nor there, at least were I live, boiled ham, which is cooked by construction is also always kept in the fridge and so is salami, once it is opened.
Example source link (German only):
https://praxistipps.focus.de/kann-man-sucuk-roh-essen-was-sie-dazu-wissen-sollten_133024

Sucuk is meant to be sliced and cooked in a pan. Traditionally served with scrambled or fried eggs. I am Turkish myself, here is a simple recipe for you to follow.
Store the rest of the sucuk in a cool place, in the fridge or freezer.

Without saying or knowing anything about the health aspect, I'd like to add one piece of information: cooked sucuk (roasted on an open flame preferably, but can be fried) is spicy. Raw sucuk is somewhat tangy and not spicy. Cooking it is likely to be the safer option, but I like the tanginess better, so I grew up eating it raw (whenever possible; i.e., parents not around). ;-)
